# Che cosa significa "ma il domani che scoperta" in questo contesto (canzone)?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Che cosa significa "ma il domani che scoperta" in questo Brano musicale - [**Figli**](https://italiasempre.com/mobile/index.php?lang=it&canzone=figli1) - Toto Cutugno

Figli innamorati che ti svegliano di notte
e non ti fanno dormire,
Figli spaventati dalla droga violentati
che si lasciano morire,
Figli ormai lontani come sudano le mani
quando suonano alla porta,
Figli delicati sempre in casa coccolati
**ma il domani che scoperta**.

Comment: Non so cos'altro fare per accettare le mie domande

Comment: Sto cancellando i miei account, non ci sono persone che vogliono aiutare ma che vogliono obbedire alle regole americane

Comment: C'è qualcuno che insegue le mie domande e fa il downvoting. Ho pietà di questo giovane, un uomo infelice.

Comment: Non inseguo domande e non faccio downvoting a prescindere. La domanda è molto mal posta e secondo me meritava un voto negativo. Non è la prima domanda del genere ed è già stato commentato che occorrerebbe qualcosa di più che riportare i versi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La punteggiatura è carente, perché è certamente un'esclamazione: *Ma, il domani, che scoperta!*

È la forma abbreviata di una frase tipo "*Ma che scoperta è/sarà il domani!*", secondo un costrutto molto comune nel parlato (ma anche nello scritto) di sottintendere il verbo nelle esclamazioni in cui si evidenzia una caratteristica eccezionale di qualcosa (*che faccia tosta (ha)!*; *che carogna (è)!*) e, alla bisogna, di indicarne il soggetto per inciso (*che faccia tosta (ha), tuo padre!*; *che carogna (era), Mussolini!*).

La puoi prendere semplicemente per quello che dice: il domani (cioè il futuro) di quei figli sarà una scoperta eccezionale (non mi è chiaro se per loro o per chi nutre delle aspettative nei loro confronti).